# Proof: A open connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is path Connected.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

$\textbf{Prove : An open connected subspace of }$  $\mathbb{R}^2$  $\textbf{is  path Connected.}$

I know there are other  proofs of this statement here.BUt i want a proof verification and how to complete my proof in this particular way.So it is not a repost!!!

$\textbf{PROOF}$:

Let $A$ an open subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now let  $x_0 \in A$ . I know there exist a nbh of $x_0$ Call it $B(x_o,ε) \subset A$ since $A$ is open.Now take a limit point of that ball That exist inside $A$  call it $y_o$ and it doesnt belong in the ball. That $y_o$ exists since if didnt belong in $A \setminus Β(x_o,ε)$ it must belong in $B(x_0,ε)$ Then $B(x_0,ε)$ is clopen in $A$ which is connected so contradiction. Now Since i know its existence connect $x_0$ with $y_o$ with the $f(x)=(1-t)x_0+t(y_o)$ Connect those points. Is continuous .Now do the same thing for $y_o$. And do that for all $x \in A$. and hence $A= \bigcup B(x,ε) $ for the right $ε>0$ and i have connected each center of the balls.

$$\textbf{Problem}:$$ I can do my described proof for the first open nbrh of $x_0$ . And get the first 2 nbrh.But on the third what if my $y_o$ is a limit point of my second nbrh in $A$ but belongs to a previous nbrh? Mean i might not take the whole $A$ after all.How do i surprass this problem? $$\textbf{So in other words how do i make sure every nbrh is not a subset of the previous one!!!}$$

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/users/137954/henno-brandsma?tab=accounts  !!You helped me before maybe you could take a look on this

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You could maybe take a look

Comment: This is a nice idea. I'm having a little bit of trouble seeing how you can actually obtain a covering of $A$ like this, though. For instance, suppose we have some open set of area $2\alpha$. Then, it might be the case that the $k^{th}$ ball might have area $\frac{\alpha}{2^k}$. So, we would end up in a situation where the total area of our covering is no more than
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha}{2^k}=\alpha< 2\alpha.$$
In such a case, we know that we certainly have not covered $A$.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis yes !! exactly what im having problem with as i wrote after the proof!!So i might have to play with the epsilons

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how well this construction can be controlled. There does not appear to be anything stopping your construction from oscillating back and forth and never covering $A$.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis I think you are right.  If i somehow prove that maybe there exists a covering of $A$ of open sets of $A$ that their intersection is empty. and use the limiti points of these sets? And make sure that the line connecting their centers is inside $A$ since every point of the line is in either nbrh .But that seems like a whole other proof i guess.

Comment: You won't find such a covering. Once you insert an open $U\subset A$, you have $\partial U \cap A\ne \varnothing,$ as long as $U\ne A$. Now, one of the other opens $V$ you place in $A$ must contain some part of $\partial U\cap A$. Any such $V$ must also intersect $U$.